# Resolve error: An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I am trying to build a docker image by running the command:

```
docker build -t user:repository .
```

and keep getting this error:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'` succeeds before bundling.
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bundler && bundle install"' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

**What I've Tried**

1. gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'`

   gets an error

   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2' (= 0.4.5), here is why:
             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

and after running the suggestion from [this](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) repo and [this](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#installing-using-update-packages) website I get the error:

Could not find a valid gem 'C:rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem' (>= 0) in any repository

I am stuck at this point for I have no idea where this problem stems from. Any help would be very much appreciated.

When I run bundle update I get an

```
Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about
OpenSSL certificates, see. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run `bundle update`. I had a similar problem and that worked for me... good luck!

Comment: @ Ronan Lopes I get an Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about
OpenSSL certificates, see . To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile would be useful here, but let's take a random stab.

If you use ubuntu, the base install does not include any ca certificates so SSL does not work properly.    Try installing the packages 'ssl' and 'ca-certificates'.

Comment: to get the ssl package would I run 'brew install openssl'? How would I install these packages on a mac? I've tried installing openssl with no prevail.

Comment: If you are running OSX inside your container -- I got nothing.   What is your container based on?